# Driver issues Windows 8.1 Pro on Late 2011 MBP

Tags: macbook-pro, windows

I installed Windows 8.1 pro on my late 2011 mbp and now I'm having issues with audio and display drivers. I can't get the audio to work at all. I have tried updating the drivers and reinstalling them, but nothing has worked.I am also having trouble with my display driver because I can't project to an external monitor. I have also tried updating drivers and reinstalling, but nothing has helped. I don't really know what to do now, but open to any suggestions on how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking this might be best asked on a Windows board but...

How did you update and reinstall the drivers?

I would download the latest BootCamp drivers and then go into device manager, find the devices in question and right-click on them and select uninstall. Simply reinstalling often doesn't fix driver issues, you gotta remove the old ones completely first.

Once the problematic drivers are uninstalled reboot.

Windows will likely detect the missing drivers and reinstall them from it's cache. If it doesn't use the drivers you downloaded from Apple